# Distributed mapping and lookup with Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to build a hashmap using text files and map values using that hashmap.

The files are already in HDFS.

I want to map data using this hashmap.

The text files are fairly small (I have around 10 files each few MB that I need to use for building the hashmap).

If the files are already on HDFS is there anything else that I can do to optimize the processing, so that building the hashmap and the lookup will happen in a distributed fashion?

Comment: Did you get a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Although the effect depends on your data set and operations, here are options I come up with

1. Optimize text format (Avro, Kryo etc) so that hashmap can build quickly
2. Combine the files into one HDFS file and increase *block replication factor* of the file, so that many Spark executors can get read the files locally
3. Use *Spark broadcast variables* for the hashmap so that executors don't need to deserialize it

Comment: Aren't broadcast variables immutable?

Comment: They're immutable. Spark driver program initializes it from the files.